# Save column value in db from model in magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento, i have added one column named as "created" , datatype is date in table core_website but value not saving in db

**My code:**

```
     $website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
     $website->setCode(strtolower($params['storename']))
                        ->setName($params['storename'])         
                        ->setcreated($currentdate)
                        ->save();
```

Current date is not saving in created column. 
Please any one help me to resolve this

Comment: Fix setcreated() into setCreated() and make sure you have refreshed the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Does **$website** contains the field **created**. Have you added the  field **created** yourself because by default there is no field called **created** in the table `core_website`.

So may be this would be the case why data is not being saved.

If there is the field than correct the word from **setcreated()** to **setCreated()**.This should not be the issue but also try it.

Hope this will help.